# Facebook Login not working after renaming VIew Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift3, facebook-login

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBOXpl-Zjmw) on how to rename a Swift controller. My controller was previously named FirestViewController. It is now named LoginViewController.

I know the rename worked because the project builds and runs correctly in the virtual environment. However the `ViewDidLoad` function that holds my Facebook Login code does not work. I am using the Swift Cocoapods SDK.

Any ideas as to why the app runs but the Facebook Login button is missing would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my new LoginViewController code file:

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookLogin

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError! ) {
        /*
            Check for successful login and act accordingly.
            Perform your segue to another UIViewController here.
         */
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! SecondViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        // Actions for when the user logged out goes here
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

EDIT 2: New code after suggested changes:

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookLogin

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error! ) {
        /*
            Check for successful login and act accordingly.
            Perform your segue to another UIViewController here.
         */
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! SecondViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        // Actions for when the user logged out goes here
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show some codes from your ViewDidLoad function that holds my Facebook Login code does not work to find out what's your problem.

Comment: @QuocLe I have added the requested code above.

Comment: Try change to "class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate". And in viewDidLoad add this code: loginButton.delegate = self

Comment: @QuocLe I made the changes as you suggested, cleaned the build, successfully recompiled the code, ran it and same thing. No login button is showing.

Here is the new code.

Comment: Is your viewDidLoad function even being called? Try setting a debugging breakpoint in it to verify.

Comment: I added the following to ViewDidLoad and it is not showing up. If my viewDidLoad override is not working, how can i fix it?

`print("hello")
let cat = ""; print(cat)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue thanks to the pointers by Kevin Vaughan. After adding break points to my code, I noticed it was never breaking at these points suggesting the code was not being executed.

I had to update the absolute path to the view controller for the storyboard to finally read the code.